# sd-toolkit sdk for barcode scanning on iPhone, does it work with the camera?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

Like the question says, can you scan a barcode with the camera? or do you have to have the barcode on an image in the phone?

Comment: Yes you can do that with the camera.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, so it is only in the trial you download it does not enable the camera?

Comment: I found out that 1 of the samples actually shows this feature. Does anyone have any experience with the sdk, any problems with it?